# Как собрать статический tar с поддержкой selinux и xattrs

Tags: компиляция, build, static, tar

Сразу говорю сюда вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595463/how-to-build-a-static-tar-command не посылать. Это проблему не решает.
Собраться то собирается нормально, только вот на --selinux говорит что не поддерживает. Собираю tar. 1.3.0 из исходников на ubuntu 16.04 на платформе arm.

Что ещё ему нужно чтоб включить поддержку? Может ещё какие то доп пакеты устанавливать?

Comment: В самой убунте-то SELinux есть и включен?

Comment: Оказалось, что ядро не поддерживает selinux. Есть способ обойти это? Без включения селинуха в самой ОС?

Comment: Обойти что? У вас tar уже собран с поддержкой selinux, всё отлично. Очевидно, на линуксе без поддержки selinux tar с ним использовать не получится, как ни собирай :)